# How can I know via API how many fields are allowed to create in custom object

Tags: custom-field, tooling-api, professional-edition

I am trying to create sql table structure in salesforce as an object. In salesforce, there is a field limitation that allows only creation of 100 fields (I am using PE). My SQL table contains more than 200 fields. Is there a way to know how many fields have left for creation so I do not hit the field limit issue. I need an API-based solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, use [EntityLimit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitylimit.htm?search_text=EntityLimit) of Tooling API

> Represents the limits for an object as displayed in the Setup UI.

you need to look `CustomFields` type and get `Remaining` field value.

---

Example, how to get all `Account` limits in Apex:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
req.setEndpoint('https://instance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Type,+Label,+Remaining,+Max,+EntityDefinitionid+FROM+EntityLimit+where+EntityDefinitionid+=+\'Account\'' );
req.setMethod('GET');
Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

---

response is:

```
{
    "size": 11,
    "totalSize": 11,
    "done": true,
    "queryLocator": null,
    "entityTypeName": "EntityLimit",
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CustomFields"
            },
            "Type": "CustomFields",
            "Label": "Custom Fields",
            "Remaining": 451,
            "Max": 500,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.RollupSummary"
            },
            "Type": "RollupSummary",
            "Label": "Rollup Summary Fields",
            "Remaining": 23,
            "Max": 25,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CustomRelationship"
            },
            "Type": "CustomRelationship",
            "Label": "Custom Relationship Fields",
            "Remaining": 39,
            "Max": 40,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveRules"
            },
            "Type": "ActiveRules",
            "Label": "Active Workflow Rules",
            "Remaining": 42,
            "Max": 50,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.TotalRules"
            },
            "Type": "TotalRules",
            "Label": "Total Workflow Rules",
            "Remaining": 492,
            "Max": 500,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ApprovalProcesses"
            },
            "Type": "ApprovalProcesses",
            "Label": "Approval Processes",
            "Remaining": 500,
            "Max": 500,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveLookupFilters"
            },
            "Type": "ActiveLookupFilters",
            "Label": "Active Lookup Filters",
            "Remaining": 5,
            "Max": 5,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.ActiveValidationRules"
            },
            "Type": "ActiveValidationRules",
            "Label": "Active Validation Rules",
            "Remaining": 95,
            "Max": 100,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.VLookup"
            },
            "Type": "VLookup",
            "Label": "VLOOKUP Functions",
            "Remaining": 10,
            "Max": 10,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.SharingRules"
            },
            "Type": "SharingRules",
            "Label": "Sharing Rules (Both Owner- and Criteria-based)",
            "Remaining": 292,
            "Max": 300,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "EntityLimit",
                "url": "/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityLimit/Account.CbsSharingRules"
            },
            "Type": "CbsSharingRules",
            "Label": "Sharing Rules (Criteria-based Only)",
            "Remaining": 49,
            "Max": 50,
            "EntityDefinitionId": "Account"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oleksandr Berehovskiy, Thank you for the reply!! I will check it out.